# Style the next tag/class with condition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to add some style to the element next to the given element but only in case the given element has some special style like `display: none;`.

```
<style>
    .twentyfive {font-size: 25px;}
    .twentyfive + .fifty {font-size: 50px;}
</style>

<div class="twentyfive" style="display: none;">25</div>
<div class="fifty">50</div>
    <br /><br />
<div class="twentyfive">25</div>
<div class="fifty">Not 50</div>
```

In the given example `.fifty` div should only scale to 50px in case it follows the `.twentyfive` div with `style="display: none;"`.

What should I add to the CSS?

Or it is only possible with JavaScript? In such case what should be the script?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a different solution is:

```css
.twentyfive {font-size: 25px;}
[data-disp="no"] { display: none; }
[data-disp="no"] + .fifty  {font-size: 50px;}
```

```html
<div class="twentyfive" data-disp="no">25</div>
<div class="fifty">50</div>
    <br /><br />
<div class="twentyfive">25</div>
<div class="fifty">Not 50</div>
```

Comment: I can't change the `div` tag content as it is strictly predefined. But I can use `[style="display: none;"] + .fifty {}`! So, thank you for the clue! ))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class for the `display: none`:

```
<style>
    .twentyfive {font-size: 25px;}
    .twentyfive.display-none + .fifty {font-size: 50px;}
    .display-none {display: none;}
</style>

<div class="twentyfive display-none">25</div>
<div class="fifty">50</div>
    <br /><br />
<div class="twentyfive">25</div>
<div class="fifty">Not 50</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the class as it is predefined.